# Broken cooperation of debian mini.iso with local repository

Tags: debian, system-installation, mirror

I maintain our isolated network for specific tasks. For easy install debian system, choosing and adding the additional packages we have an easy configurable lighttpd- web server with full debian repository mirror. I download the mirror once per year with `apt-mirror`, single architecture amd64, testing/stable/oldstable, and the corresponding netinstall mini.iso onto a USB externeal HD. Then I copy all downloaded files to our web server, and also reconfigure files of the BootP server, to use the new mini.iso images. Additionaly I use to prepare a mobile repository of stable version on a USB flash disk for the Linux notebooks which are used off the office (`deb file:///path/debian stable main contrib`).

Everything worked fine, but this year I cannot use the new local repository for debian installation using **netinst** `mini.iso`, and the mobile repository also cannot be used. The formerly installed Linux can use the new local mirror using http protocol.

I cannot determine the main reason, because the netinst mini.iso just says „your mirror does not work“ but there are no logs, no details. The communication with the mobile repo indicates that there may be some problem with GPG. But the error/warninig messages also say that apt-get update cannot download the Release and InRelease files, even that these files do exist in the announced path.

Well, I can accept the trend for better security on the Internet, but I would like to be either supported with valuable (optimally illustrated with examples) information how to kiss the local repository to wake it up, or how to switch off the security barriers for the fundamentally secure environment, as the isolated net or file connected repo definitely have to be.

Do you know the certain way how to and what to repair in ought to be able to regain the PXE netinstalation from an isolated debian repository?

After some experiments:

We found, that one error comes from the multi-arch repository: I downloaded amd64 and i386. The client asks for `Contents-all` file, but the `apt-mirror` did not mirrored it. We downloaded these files manually, and some errors dismissed. But some other errors persist. We tried to create new GPG signatures, but no effect.

The other suspected source of errors may be the `mini.iso`. It can content some config, in which we can remove the GPG requests, or add some trusted `gpg keys`. But even so small, it is not well documented. We can try to ask the maintainers for help.

Comment: There are various mailing list in Debian, which may be more relevant (to answer your question, but also in a way Debian know what users uses/needs).

Comment: Problem is, that the general how-tos assume that the mirror-server  as the box to be installed are connected to public, and hence the gig key can be certified over the Internet. My network is isolated, and there is no way to as Internet authority for verification.

Comment: Tell Debian about it. I'm sure you are not the only with such scenario. Really.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was my fault. I lost my `/etc/apt/mirror.list` config file and my *step by step procedure* from my last mirror-update.
As the debian installation uses `udeb` packages (packages without obligatory man and other features) it is necessary to add the `main/debian-installer` section.
The `/etc/apt/mirror.list` may content this:

```
set base_path  /media/<user>/transport_disk/mirror
... 
set defaultarch amd64
...
deb http://nearest.mirror.cz/debian bookworm main main/debian-installer contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

Do not forget to download an corresponding `mini.iso`.

You can download all version of debian, but there are supported just four of them: **testing, stable, oldstable and oldoldstable**. At present time (2023-06-23) these are:

```
trixie    - testing
bookworm  - stable
bullseye  - oldstable
buster    - oldoldstable
```

Elder version can be find at various archive sites: http://archive.debian.org/debian/  or  http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/debian-archive/dists/

Downloaded files then must be copied to the filesystem of your local web server, let’s say in the `/var/mirrors/2023-06/` directory. It is sufficient to copy just the  `. . ./debian/*` directory. Do not forget, that all files and directories have to be readable by that user, running the web server (in my case: `lighttpd` runs under `www-data` user). After you finish, you must be able to open your mirror web-server in any local browser: `http://local.web.server/debian`
to see:

```
../
dists/
pool/
```

and in the path: `http://local.web.server/debian/dists/bookworm/main/`

```
../
binary-amd64/
debian-installer/
dep11/
Contents-amd64.gz
```

The other environment you need:

```
BootP server 
tftp server 
DNS server (optional)
PXE bootloader
```

The first three can be easily realized with `dnsmasq` as you can find at: http://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall
The possible bootloaders are `pxelinux` or `grub`. The former suits me well but the project freezes and cannot be used with **uEFI** only systems.

If you try to add some other architecture to your local mirror, you have to download

/debian/<*version*>/<*section*>/`Contents-all.gz`

files manually and put them into the correct path. I did not find any config option to tell `apt-mirror` to downloaded them on the run.

After you install your local linux box, it can be recommended to add in `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://your.local.webserver/debian <version> main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

and add in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10no-check`

```
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
```

especially while using the testing version because it changes quickly.

I hope, it will help somebody.